# Sketch of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Sketch $r(t)e^{it} $
with $r(t)=1+0.1\sin (100t)$

I've already plotted it and it looked like $e^{it}$ to me, but with a lot of harmonics.
Is there a way to sketch it in a Re-Im plane? Or am I missing the big picture here?

Comment: It is a perturbated circle. But what do you mean by "is there a way to sketch it" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $r(t)$ is the magnitude of the complex number. Hence, $r(t)e^{it}$ is a unit circle with added oscillations in the radius from $0.9$ to $1.1$. So all the "action" happens in a region between a circle with radius $0.9$ and another circle with radius $1.1$.